# let users select files from different moments in a Git Source Tree

Tags: php, git

I recently created a feature where a user can select an older or new version of text using a php-git library called php.git.

When a users selects an older version/tag number, php checkouts out the local git repository and then the file loads from that point in the source tree.

My question is: is this going to be a problem if more than one person is trying access the website at the same time?

Might these users be competing against each other, repeatedly checking out the git repo to different branches.

I wonder if it is better to quickly do something like a git-archive to a temp folder, and then load the desired files from the temp folder, but to always keep the main repo itself at the the head/master position.

Any thoughts or concerns?

Comment: git-php library is: http://github.com/kbjr/Git.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if all your PHP processes are just writing to the same directory without yielding, you have an obvious race condition.

You should link to the library you're using so it's clear.  As far a solution, you should probably extract the content of the desired version using the library, then cache it (e.g. in memacached) for a reasonable amount of time.